# In Active Admin index page how to display two table data like tab.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two different models. I want to display that both table data in Active Admin Index Page like tab. In one tab one table data display and in other tab 2nd table data display

Answer (score 0):

- Consider a [custom page](http://www.activeadmin.org/10-custom-pages.html) with [table_for components](http://www.activeadmin.org/12-arbre-components.html)
- Consider not using ActiveAdmin.  It wasn't designed to do this, perhaps it is the wrong tool to use.